# Access Upsizing - Property 'Attributes' already exists for 'table'

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, upsizing

I'm trying to use Access's upsizing wizard to move the data from Access to SQL Server. I'm currently on this error but can't figure out where the property is coming from;

```
Property 'Attributes' already exists for 'table'.
```

The SQL its trying to run is;

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty N'Attributes', N'2', N'user', N'dbo', N'table', N'table', N'column', N'ID'
```

But the table in Access doesn't include an ID column and I can't see anything in the properties on the table to indicate why it's trying to add the property for SQL Server.

In the wizard guide I chose not to import any extras like indexes, triggers etc.

Any ideas why the wizard is doing this and how to stop it trying to create the properties?

Alternatively, are there any other tools which would moved the data from Access to MSSQL while keeping Access front-end objects in place and working?

Comment: are you using the SSMA or the built in accss tools? I would suggest you use Sql Server Migration Assistant for Access. The built in up-sizing tools are now deprecated, and they don't work near as well as the separate (and free) SSMA tool. Just google SSMA for access and give that a try.

Answer (score 2):

The upsizing wizard had its deficiencies from the start, and has been removed from recent versions of Access. I recommend not using it.

Personally, I have a form that handles upsizing for me. It's a form with on it two text boxes named `ConStr` and `adoString` (the first containing the connection string for Access to use including the `ODBC;` prefix, the second containing either an ODBC or OLEDB string for ADO to use), a button named `ToSQL`, and a listbox named `lstTables`. It contains the following code:

To populate the local tables on load:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    lstTables.RowSourceType = "Value List"
    Dim iterator As Variant
    For Each iterator In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If Not iterator.NAME Like "MSys*" And Not iterator.NAME Like "~*" Then
            lstTables.AddItem iterator.NAME
        End If
    Next iterator
End Sub
```

To move the tables over to SQL server:

```vb
Private Sub ToSQL_Click()
    Dim i1 As Variant
    Dim td As DAO.TableDef
    Dim NewTd As DAO.TableDef
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    'Iterate through all selected tables
    With lstTables
        For Each i1 In .ItemsSelected
            Set td = db.TableDefs(.ItemData(i1))
            'Add a primary key if none exist
            'AddPK td 'Not providing this one as it's not part of normal upscaling
            'Move the table to SQL server
            DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "ODBC Database", _
            conStr _
            , acTable, .ItemData(i1), .ItemData(i1)
            'Rename the local table to name_local
            td.NAME = .ItemData(i1) & "_local"
            'Change the remote table to the schema specified
            'ADOChangeSchema GetDefaultSchema(), "mySchema", .ItemData(i1) 'Not providing this one as it's not part of normal upscaling
            'Set the primary key in SQL server
            ADOAddPrimaryKey GetDefaultSchema(), .ItemData(i1), GetPKName(td)
            'Create a new linked table, linking to the remote table
            Set NewTd = db.CreateTableDef(.ItemData(i1), 0, GetDefaultSchema() & .ItemData(i1), conStr)
            db.TableDefs.Append NewTd
        Next i1
    End With
End Sub
```

And some helper functions:

```vb
Public Sub ADOAddPrimaryKey(SchemaName As String, tableName As String, FieldName As String)
On Error GoTo SetNotNull
    Dim conn As Object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Dim cmd As Object
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    conn.Open adoString
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE " & SchemaName & ".[" & tableName & "] ADD CONSTRAINT [" & tableName & "_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([" & FieldName & "]);"
    cmd.Execute
    Exit Sub
SetNotNull:
    If Err.Number = -2147217900 Then
        cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE " & SchemaName & ".[" & tableName & "] ALTER COLUMN [" & FieldName & "] INTEGER NOT NULL"
        cmd.Execute
        cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE " & SchemaName & ".[" & tableName & "] ADD CONSTRAINT [" & tableName & "_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([" & FieldName & "]);"
        cmd.Execute
    Else
        Err.Raise Err.Number
    End If
End Sub

Public Function GetDefaultSchema() As String
    Dim conn As Object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Dim rs As Object
    conn.Open adoString
    Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT SCHEMA_NAME()")
    GetDefaultSchema = rs.Fields(0)
End Function

Public Function GetPKName(td As DAO.TableDef) As String
'Returns the name of the first field included in the primary key (WARNING! Doesn't return all fields for composite primary keys!)
    Dim idx As DAO.Index
    For Each idx In td.Indexes
        If idx.Primary Then
            GetPKName = idx.Fields(0).NAME
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next idx
End Function
```

This form only preserves data and the primary key, and makes several assumptions (too lazy to avoid them), such as: table names don't contain square brackets, there are no composite primary keys, the table schema is safe for use in SQL statements, there are no attachment fields or multivalued fields, and there are no relationships (had a version that preserved relationships, but... I honestly don't know where it is now).

It also leaves a renamed copy of the local table. The original version then tests 1K random rows to check if the content is identical, but I've omitted that for brevity.

You can use this as a starting point, since it might need tuning to suit your specific needs.

Comment: This is awesome, I'll let you know how it goes.